# How to regconize incognito mode and open new tab in an existing incognito window?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

i am not professional developer.
and i just make one Chrome extension app.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/%EB%84%A4%EC%9D%B4%EB%B2%84-%EA%B2%80%EC%83%89/bkkebjanfcchfakehopacbbpogflmdie?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon

This app just makes CONTEXT MENU and open window new chrome tab.
but one of my user wants me to make this app works in incognito mode. (open window with incognito mode)

i really tried many times.
but i can`t understand how to recognize incognito mode and how to make new incognito tab in same window.
This is my last try
and please help me... thanks

```
chrome.extension.isAllowedIncognitoAccess(function(isAllowedAccess) 
{
 if (isAllowedAccess) return;
  window.open("http://search.naver.com/search.naver?ie=utf8&query=" + itemData.selectionText, '_blank');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The context menu listener receives a [tab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab) object in the [second parameter](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#event-onClicked) so let's reuse its `windowId` property via [chrome.tabs.create](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create):

```js
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
  chrome.tabs.create({
    url: 'http://search.naver.com/search.naver?ie=utf8&query=' +
      encodeURIComponent(info.selectionText),
    windowId: tab.windowId,
    openerTabId: tab.id,
  });
});
```

P.S. With `openerTabId`, when this new tab will be closed by the user, the focus will be automatically set to the specified tab regardless of its relative position in the tab strip.

Comment: Thanks a lot to your answer. I used your code right away... But it doesn`t work in incognito mode.